# modalpopupextender have an element.style

Tags: css, asp.net, modalpopupextender

i have created modal popup extender and it worked! but i cant change the style in it.
this is the code for the ModalPopupExtender. As you can see, the style for the panel is none.

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="mpe" runat="server"
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkDummy" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID = "btnHide">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ClientIDMode="Static" ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none">
    <div class="header">
        Modal Popup
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        This is a Modal Popup.
        <br />
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Modal Popup" />
      </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

but when I run it at browser, i got this. the style is there which is 
`<div id="pnlPopup" class="modalPopup" style="position: fixed; z-index: 10002; left: 810px; top: 248px;">`

[image]

can somebody help me? how to remove that style, or customized it? where is that style come from?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is attribute for modalpopupextender called RepositionMode. this attribute control the position of modalpopupextender automatically.